# KDE Partition Manager can't regrow my EXT4 partition after shrinking it?

Tags: debian, partition, initramfs, bootable

*I'm sorry if I mix different units in this but these are the units I see when working.*

I decided to add a new partition to my bootable sd card which contained a 21GB partition of an EXT4 file system (Debian with KDE) and about 8GB of linux swapspace on another partition, using KDE partition manager on my Raspberry Pi (as opposed to the PC I usually use with my bootable drive).

I made the stupid decision to try and shrink and move both partitions to allow myself a blank NTFS partition of about 11GiB for using with any Windows device. This partitioned fine but upon choosing Debian at GRUB on my PC, initramfs told me that my filesystem was probably corrupt and that I couldn't boot properly. The supposed file system size of 21 odd GB was larger than the available device (partition) size of 15GB and it couldn't continue.

Trying to backpedal my decision, I took the sd card out and used my RPi to reformat it back to how it was. Everything worked fine, moving partitions about and resizing the swap space. However, KDE partition manager was unable to grow ext4 to its original size (see images 1, 2 and 3).

Can anything be done to get things back to normal, or failing that, restore *some* of the data on the ext4 filesystem? I didn't have any irreplaceable documents on there really but I got a lot of settings customised to my liking and I'd like to make the restoration process as quick as possible.

If you do have an answer, please tell me if there's any more information I can provide about my situation that I haven't already given.

After first partitioning (1):

[image: After first partitioning]

Before attempting to grow partition (2):

[image: Before]

Error! (3):

[image: Error]

============================

**In response to the first question about the details given under the error:**

============================

```
Grow partition ‘/dev/sda1’ from 14.65 GiB to 21.71 GiB 
Job: Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sda1’ 
Command: e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1 
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 5487104 blocks
The physical size of the device is 3840000 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes
 

Command: e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1 
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 5487104 blocks
The physical size of the device is 3840000 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes
 
Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sda1’: Error

Checking partition ‘/dev/sda1’ before resize/move failed. 
Grow partition ‘/dev/sda1’ from 14.65 GiB to 21.71 GiB: Error
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your filesystem for some reason is bigger than partition.
Not sure how you got into this state, this shouldn't happen with partition manager.
Anyway, it will now refuse to work for you until you manually fix it. Best way to proceed is to fix partition size with fdisk. Delete old partition and recreate with the same starting position but big enough to accomodate all 5487104 blocks (One block is 4096 bytes, one sector in fdisk should be 512 bytes), so you would need 5487104 * 8 sectors.

Then you can try increasing it with KDE Partition Manager to your desired size.